# Malformed URL powershell spaces in filename

Tags: powershell

I am using the following script to create URLs.

```
$files1 =Get-ChildItem $ENV:WORKSPACE/Pro_result
$prefix="https://test-jenkins-a-master-black.aws.jhgf.com/job/qa/job/TestDemo_email_PDF/ws/Pro_result/"
foreach ($file in $files1) {
  write-Output ($prefix+$file.Name)
 }
```

However, I am getting a url like this and I have no control over the filename
[https://test-jenkins-a-master-black.aws.jhgf.com/job/qa/job/TestDemo_email_PDF/ws/Pro_result/W0A-209-193-210_Dealer portal](https://black.aws.jmfamily.com/job/qa/job/TestDemo_email_PDF/ws/Tosca_result/W0A-209-193-210_Dealer%20portal%20production%20smoke%20test_20220427-120342.pdf) production smoke test_20220427-120342.pdf

It breaks after `portal`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`[uri]::EscapeUriString` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapeuristring) to escape spaces and similar characters in URI paths:

```
foreach ($file in $files1) {
  [uri]::EscapeUriString($prefix+$file.Name)
}
```

This will correctly re-encode the spaces as `%20`, resulting in a valid URL with no whitespace a la:

```
https://test-jenkins-a-master-black.aws.jhgf.com/job/qa/job/TestDemo_email_PDF/ws/Pro_result/W0A-209-193-210_Dealer%20portal%20production%20smoke%20test_20220427-120342.pdf
```